# Best practice for Service and data contracts - WCF

Tags: architecture, wcf

I understand I can apply several options to the `ServiceContract` (like `Name`, `Namespace`) attribute and for `OperationContract` (`Action`, `ReplyAction`)

The same goes to `DataContract` (`Namespace`) and `DataMember` (`IsRequired`, `Name`, `Order`)

How do I determine if I need to apply a particular option or not. What is the best practice/convention I should follow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no one "best practice" here.  Just understand what all of the different arguments are used for.

- `Name` should be specified if you want the "public" name of your service to be different from the actual class name (most people don't change this).  It's similar for data contracts - use it if you want the name exposed over SOAP/MEX to be different from the property name you use internally.
- `Namespace` is something you *should* change, otherwise it defaults to `tempuri.org` - you should replace this with a namespace that's relevant to your application.
- `IsRequired` should be specified if the type is nullable (i.e. a `string`) but the field is actually required as part of the contract (for example, a customer must have a name... that is a required field).
- `Order` just changes the order that properties appear in the metadata/XML; usually most people don't bother with this unless it's required for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Does Namespace have any relation to the URL the services will be hosted in? I know I can specify any namespace I want, but was not sure if it's a good practice to have a namespace same as where the web host is located.

Comment: @DotnetDude: No, not really.  Namespace is just supposed to be a unique identifier that differentiates your `AwesomeService` from everyone else's `AwesomeService`.  If you happen to have a real production URL, it won't *hurt* you to use that (I do), but it's not a requirement.

Comment: Namespace and Name affect the shape of the generated xml and ultimately the deserialized objects on the other end of the wire.

Comment: Name is useful for exposing overloaded methods in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

There are not requirements or standards.

The attributes provide options, increasing the possibility that the static spec provided by MS will fit your needs.

So, I would say best practice is to understand the options and how to apply them to your requirements.